# pandas dataframe compare None puzzle me

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

a = [{'a':None},{'a':"11"},{'a':None}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

I try to find the 'a' which is None, So I write this:

```
df.a == None
```

and the result is:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

but I use map function:

```
df.a.map(lambda x: x == None)
```

the result is right:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

as a newbie, the different result really puzzle me..

panda version: 0.19.2

Can anybody help me? Why the first way can not work properly.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use the below function to check None.

```
df.a.isnull()
```